# Want more traditional "find" behavior in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using "find" in VSCode, I would like it to behave more traditionally, to disable how it eagerly jumps to the first partial match before I "submit" my search string, and only to jump to a match (if one exists) when I hit the enter key.  And then to exit the search dialog without me having to hit ESCAPE.

Are either of these 2 things possible?

Comment: Your second question is not possible.  The Find widget will remain open until you clear it manually somehow, whether by `escape` or in a macro which does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Configuring the Find-Widget's Auto-Jump Feature

To configure V.S. Code so that the cursor does not Jump as you type, you need to set the following configuration, as it is shown below, in your **`settings.json`** file (you can set it in the workspace, or user, settings.json file).

```
    // "./.vscode/settings.json"

    "editor.find.cursorMoveOnType": false
```

The above will cause your editors find widget to move the cursor, thus highlighting the next closest returned search result when you press **<kbd>enter</kbd>**, and only when you press **<kbd>enter</kbd>**, never before. The find-widget should close with escape weather you do, or do not, configure the cursor to *"jump on type"*.